# Discriminate Union doesn't work for function argument

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to make a discriminate union type for two possible component props, but it doesn't seem to work for the argument that I pass to the onClick function on this example:

```
type TLink = {
  label: string,
  onClick?: (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLAnchorElement>) => void,
  path: string
}

type TButton = {
  label: string,
  onClick?: (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => void,
  options: [TButtonOption, TButtonOption]
}

type TOptionalButton = TLink | TButton;

const newButton: TOptionalButton = {
  path:  'somepath',
  onClick: (e) => null,
  label: 'somelabel',
}

function handleChange(e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLAnchorElement>) {
  if(newButton.onClick) newButton.onClick(e);
}
```

I get a TS error when passing the "e" argument down to newButton.onClick(e):

> Argument of type 'MouseEvent<HTMLAnchorElement, MouseEvent>' is not
> assignable to parameter of type 'MouseEvent<HTMLAnchorElement,
> MouseEvent> & MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>'.
> ...

So, why all the props are correctly typed but not this argument?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Shouldn't it be typed `HTMLButtonElement` for handle change function? `function handleChange(e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) {`

Comment: I think  if you want pass an anchor element first you should assert it as HTMLElement and then assert it as HTMLButtonElement; something like this:  React.MouseEvent<HTMLAnchorElement as HTMLElement  as HTMLButtonElement>

Comment: @Harkunwar It is the anchor type, because it has the `path` property inside it, so it will infer that the type is `TLink`.

Comment: @Ebay It is either a `HTMLAnchorElement` or `HTMLButtonElement` based on the inference of the discriminate type (if it has the `path` property set or not). It should get the onClick of the `HTMLAnchorElement` since it has the path. Every other prop is typed correctly

Comment: @Rodolfo, TypeScript doesn't know if `newButton` is an Anchor Element or a Button Element, which is why it's throwing the above error because you've defined `TOptionalButton` as `TLink | TButton`

Comment: @Harkunwar isn't that how discriminated unions work? I mean, if I try to pass options, it throws me this: `Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'options' does not exist in type 'OptionalButtonLink'.` So it knows it is `OptionalButtonLink` and should know that `onClick` receives a `HTMLAnchorElement`. If I remove the `path` key, it accepts the `options` key, because it's then of `TOptionalButton` type.

Comment: I think you need to check the path or options property; by checking onClick both of TLink and TButton has this property, so the discrimination could be done

Comment: if(newButton.path) { // here; ts sure the newButton is from anchor; newButton.onClick(e); }

Comment: @Ebay if I add a new property `bla` that is `number` in `TOptionalButton` and `string` in TOptional link, and try to use assign a `string` to when I have a `path`: `Type '{ onClick: (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLAnchorElement>) => null; label: string; path: string; bla: string; }' is not assignable to type 'OptionalButton'.
  Types of property 'bla' are incompatible.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'`

Comment: @Ebay, I tried that as well, didn't work

Answer (score 2):

Typescript doesn't know which of two types do you want to use in this particular case, as the `onClick` method looks the same for both variants but with different generic type of it's argument. The TS v4 can detect union type via a property in some, more simple cases, but not in this one.

Your idea looks reasonable: if there is a `path` property, consider it as `TLink`, otherwise it's `TButton`. But the TS thinks a bit different. It gets the typed object which might contain `path` or `options`, and tries to validate, which of two properties can be used here. To do that it needs implicitly know what generic type do you gonna use in the onClick, what is not clear in your current solution.

You have to give the TS any hint to help it understand what do you really expect here.

One of possible solutions

```js
interface TBaseButton<T extends HTMLAnchorElement | HTMLButtonElement> {
  label: string;
  onClick?: (e: React.MouseEvent<T>) => void;
}

interface TLink extends TBaseButton<HTMLAnchorElement> {
  path: string;
}

interface TButton extends TBaseButton<HTMLButtonElement> {
  options: [TButtonOption, TButtonOption];
}

type TOptionalButton<T extends HTMLAnchorElement | HTMLButtonElement> = T extends HTMLAnchorElement
  ? TLink
  : TButton;

const newButton: TOptionalButton<HTMLAnchorElement> = {
  path: 'somepath',
  onClick: (e) => null,
  label: 'somelabel',
};

function handleChange(e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLAnchorElement>) {
  if (newButton.onClick) newButton.onClick(e);
}
```

Another solution, you can make onClick argument more abstract so it will depend on the input type. It will help to solve the `onClick` argument intersection, but won't help TS to define the newButton exact type, you will see only common properties:

```js
interface TBaseButton<T extends HTMLAnchorElement | HTMLButtonElement> {
  label: string;
  onClick: <T>(e: React.MouseEvent<T>) => void;
}

interface TLink extends TBaseButton<HTMLAnchorElement> {
  path: string;
}

interface TButton extends TBaseButton<HTMLButtonElement> {
  options: [TButtonOption, TButtonOption];
}

type TOptionalButton = TLink | TButton;

const newButton: TOptionalButton = {
  path: 'somepath',
  onClick: (e) => null,
  label: 'somelabel',
};

function handleChange(e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLAnchorElement>) {
  if (newButton.onClick) newButton.onClick(e);
}
```

One more solution, you can implicitly define the type using custom helper:

```js
interface TBaseButton<T extends HTMLAnchorElement | HTMLButtonElement> {
  label: string;
  onClick: (e: React.MouseEvent<T>) => void;
}

interface TLink extends TBaseButton<HTMLAnchorElement> {
  path: string;
}

interface TButton extends TBaseButton<HTMLButtonElement> {
  options: [TButtonOption, TButtonOption];
}

type TOptionalButton = TLink | TButton;

function isTLink(value: TOptionalButton): value is TLink {
  return 'path' in value;
}

function isTButton(value: TOptionalButton): value is TButton {
  return 'options' in value;
}

const newButton: TOptionalButton = {
  path: 'somepath',
  onClick: (e) => null,
  label: 'somelabel',
};

function handleChange(e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLAnchorElement>) {
  if (isTLink(newButton)) {
    // now TS is sure the newButton is actually TLink

    if (newButton.onClick) newButton.onClick(e);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks a lot for the answer and the explanation. But I'm afraid it's not an option to pass a generic in this case, since these objects will go inside a config that is used inside some micro frontends. Is there anyway to infer that type based on another prop, like I would like it to?
I had the same problem with a select component, which could be `multiple` and then the onChange function would receive an `string[]` instead of `string`, but I came across the same problem...

Comment: I've added one more solution. It also won't solve all problems, but works a bit different.

Comment: That worked for the onClick function! But unfortunately broke the other features such as not allowing `options` to be passed if there's a `path`. I wonder if this is even achievable the way that I want. lol

Comment: I published one more workaround via helper

Comment: That works too for the `onClick` just like the solution before it, but still removes the checking of the other keys, like the `options` key inside a `TLink`, for example.

Comment: There is no `options` property in the `TLink`. Once you define the type via helper the object now considered as `TLink` or `TButton`, but not both simultaneously. So, `if (isTLink(newButton)) { /* here the the newButton is considered as TLink exactly */ } else { /* here the the newButton is considered as TButton exactly */ }`

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if 'path' exists in newButton. Update your `handleChange` function in the following way:

```js
function handleChange(e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLAnchorElement>) {
  if (newButton.onClick && 'path' in newButton) newButton.onClick(e);
}
```

Working example from [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4BYAKCpgE8wk4AVAGWADsBrOAXjgG8qcOABsUAIyQiAXHADOMKBwDmAGiFwI7AMIjgaTgH5ZACiSzk6GADoAshACucpAFEAbknYwAPAAkmtiwAguxoABbQLiJIIJ4wAHwAlLzxcG4QwAAm6pTCYCgwYbIKSuzKVAC%20VDT0jEwAQg4wMFq8AhpikjLyiio5wlq6%20kam5ojENvZOrh5efgEsjc1aUTFxSSlpGdlUAPS7wppgMMBacrIA2g1NLewA8sen7KrMS7cPJ1oAupXVlHQMZgfJ4oERvVp8VgcbgAH1eNy0FGolDQZ3g7CQAHdwexZExgVpQTi2oJcnB8oVZAQ5LgkBSwvh%20podHoDKNkjxUuwHCIREzOlJZPgabEBSJGb9kZgHKFPuw4GEUOxMtFtIqykgzBYJnZHM53HF5oEQuFItFYl4NqThMBMCYMdiEexrINWdwAGTugj0-BwDhwB045KBp0ulnDMyJJEVIA)

Comment: Somehow this works in the TS Playground but not on my code. Same TS version. So strange.